# Send email on single button click

Tags: 2010, email

We have a calendar of training events for a variety of topics. I would, ideally, like there to be a button which the user can click to "register interest" in the event, which will in turn send an email to our training manager who will assess their suitability for the course. 
I had considered attaching a list to each event and using an approval workflow to accomplish something similar, however this is a pretty convoluted method considering the number of events we have running.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could create an "Interest" list and then have the "register interest" button use javascript and SharePoint web services to add an entry into the list with the corresponding event details.  You could then possibly use a workflow on the "Interest" list to send the emails.  Very similar approach to what you suggest but using a single list for all events rather than one list per event.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Dave. Unfortunately I am not javascript savvy. Would be much easier if I was...

Comment: I really can't see a 'one click' solution that doesn't involve javascript in some way so you might have to get a little more comfortable with it or hire a consultant to write it for you.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I've done one click buttons that execute javascript to trigger workflows.  You might be able to fashion up some script that triggers a site or list workflow that emails people.